# How to prevent escaping during serialization with Retrofit2 and Gson Converter

Tags: android, gson, retrofit2

I am lost in thoughts and tried my best to search and to come up with a possible solution. I have tried most of the answers that could be related to what I am trying to achieve but still no luck.

So to elaborate my question, I am receiving this response from an API

```
{
    "profileList": [
        {
          "id": "7mmfHGLc0MGtZeQNno/WFqDjlAPj26CS",
          "name": "Alexandria Victoria Maxene Kluber  van de Gr\\\"oot\""
         }
       ]
}
```

What I wanted to achieve is to get the "name" field value without the value being escaped. Because on my current setup, what I get from that response after deserialization process is `Alexandria Victoria Maxene Kluber  van de Gr\"oot""`

I let my Retrofit handle the API request and response so that's what I am getting, I currently don't want to tear off my handlers for specific reason, but I am hoping someone could point me in the right direction.
Here is my Retrofit Builder code:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                        .disableHtmlEscaping()
                        .create();
      m_builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                  .baseUrl(url)
                  .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson));
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: do you get the value after deserialisation? Gson should handle escape characters correctly. Response value and deserialized response value may differ.

Comment: @Onik the value I get after deserialization is Alexandria Victoria Maxene Kluber  van de Gr\"oot"" I may have made wrong statement in the question. What I wanted to achieve is to stop Gson from escaping those characters.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use `JsonPrimitive` in your `POJO`. See below example:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.List;

public class GsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File jsonFile = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

        System.out.println(gson.fromJson(new FileReader(jsonFile), Profiles.class));
    }
}

class Profiles {

    private List<Profile> profileList;

    // getters, setters, toString
}

class Profile {

    private String id;
    private JsonPrimitive name;

    // getters, setters, toString
}
```

Above example for your `JSON` payload prints:

```
Profiles{profileList=[Profile{id='7mmfHGLc0MGtZeQNno/WFqDjlAPj26CS', name='"Alexandria Victoria Maxene Kluber  van de Gr\\\"oot\""'}]}
```

Comment: I am currently trying to integrate that, but currently it's giving me errors on my Parceler and will it also have a conflict with my Realm? because my object is extended to RealmObject and implements Parcelable. If so, do you have any workaround for this?

Comment: @EdwardBryan does it a requirement from `Retrofit` that every response `POJO` extends `RealmObject` and implements `Parcelable`. I was not aware about this and how your `POJO` looks like.

Comment: No, not really. It's just our current app object is necessarily have to extend RealmObject for our local db and Parcelable as well. Sorry that I wasn't able to provide code snipper for the model.
But it's like this:

`@Parcel(value = Parcel.Serialization.BEAN, analyze = {Profile.class})
   public class Profile extends RealmObject implements Parcelable {`

And so on.

Comment: @EdwardBryan, I am not familiar with `Retrofit`. Does it require that `Profile` class must extend `RealmObject` and have `Parcel` annotation? Does it require to deserialize from `JSON`? Can you create simple `POJO` only for deserializing and convert to `Realm` "aware" after this?

Comment: `Retrofit` does not require the the `Profile` to be extended in `RealmObject` and have `Parcel` annotation, it is just a requirement in our project. But the repository interface automatically deserialize the `JSON` based on the object pvoided. But thanks for the idea, I'll try some workaround using that.